# Bukkit shoot tnt & help with vectors

Tags: java, vector, minecraft-modding

I want to shoot a piece of tnt from the players face and then let it explode when it hits the target block.

```
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("cannon")) {
        if(!perrmissionCheck(sender, "Needs.cannon", "cannon")){
            return true;
        }
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)){
            sender.sendMessage(nameC+"You must be a player to preform this command.");
            return true;
        }
        Block block = ((Player) sender).getTargetBlock(null, 50);
        Location location = ((Player) sender).getLocation();
        //float power = 4;
        //if (args.length == 1){
            //power = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
        //}
        sender.sendMessage(name+"BOOM!");
        double x = block.getX();
        double y = block.getY();
        double z = block.getZ();
        TNTPrimed tnt = (TNTPrimed) ((Player)sender).getWorld().spawn(location, TNTPrimed.class);
        Vector v = new Vector(x, y, z);
        tnt.setVelocity(v);
        //block.getWorld().createExplosion(location, power);
        //block.getWorld().spawn(tntLoc, TNTPrimed.class);
        return true;
    }
```

This kinda just ramdomly throws the tnt and then exploads i want to get where the player is looking and then shoot it that way if someone could also describe how the args work for new Vector(arg0, arg1, arg2) i would appreciate it...

Thanks any help is great

***EDIT***
I relize this is really old but i wanted to share how I did it,

```
    int v = 2;

    if (args.length > 1){
        v = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    final Vector direction = user.getEyeLocation().getDirection().multiply(v);

    TNTPrimed tnt = user.getWorld().spawn(user.getEyeLocation().add(direction.getX(), direction.getY(), direction.getZ()), TNTPrimed.class);

    tnt.setVelocity(direction);

    user.sendMessage(name + "Boom!");
    plugin.inGameMsg.msgAdmins(plugin.chatDark_AQUA + user.getName() + plugin.chatGray + " used cannon command!");
    return true;
```

this sends the tnt right where the player is looking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three arguments taken by Vector are its (x, y, z) components. Here's a visual representation of a Vector in 3D space:

[image]

A vector can be used to store either a displacement (e.g. movement) or a position. In this case since you're passing the vector to `setVelocity()` it's a displacement - it specifies in which direction the TNT will be *moving*.

But it's probably not working because your Vector is currently holding the *position* of the target block in the world, and what you want is the *direction* the player is facing.

Try to see in the Player class if there's already a way to get a Vector representing the way it's facing. Otherwise you'd need to calculate one from the player's rotation values.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is the answer for someone else stumbling over this problem. :)

To get the Vector for the direction of the head you have to use,

```
player.getEyeLocation().getDirection()
```

Here is a working example of the code, you may have to play around with the multiplier to get the desired result.

I also rewrote some of the chatcolors to make it work for me.

```
// Get the player and the location of the eyes (head)
Player player = (Player) sender;
Location location = player.getEyeLocation();

// Send the player a message
sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA+"BOOM!");

// Prime a tnt and place it at the location of players head         
TNTPrimed tnt = (TNTPrimed) player.getWorld().spawn(location, TNTPrimed.class);
// mulitiply the direction from the location by 2 and store it as vector
Vector v = location.getDirection().multiply(2);
// Apply the vector to the primed tnt
tnt.setVelocity(v);
```