# Bukkit shoot tnt where player is looking

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bukkit shoot tnt & help with vectors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/bukkit-shoot-tnt-help-with-vectors)

Hello. I want to shoot a piece of tnt from the players face and then let it explode when it hits the target block.

I set it up so where the player looks and type in /tnt [power] /cannon [power] or /t [power] it will blow up at the target block:

```
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("cannon")) {
        if(!perrmissionCheck(sender, "Needs.cannon", "cannon")){
            return true;
        }
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)){
            sender.sendMessage(nameC+"You must be a player to preform this command.");
            return true;
        }
        Block block = ((Player) sender).getTargetBlock(null, 50);
        Location location = block.getLocation();
        float power = 4;
        if (args.length == 1){
            power = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
        }
        sender.sendMessage(name+"BOOM!");
        block.getWorld().createExplosion(location, power);
        return true;
    }
```

That's all fine and dandy but I want it to appear in front of the user then start to move away towards the target block. And NOT blow up before it reaches the target block. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I think it may have something to do with vectors but I have no idea how to use them.

Thanks.

Comment: `Hello i am wanting to shoot a piece of tnt from the players face`. This part of the question alone made my day. Thanks for the chuckle.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector